# mongodb installation problem in ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: mongodb, installation, coredump, mongoose-web-server, mongodb-shell

I am unable to complete installation process of mongodb in ubuntu 22.04 system using terminal by following steps
Install the dependencies
apt update

apt install dirmngr gnupg apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common

Download and add the MongoDB GPG key with the following command

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list

apt-get update

apt-get install -y mongodb-org

systemctl start mongod
systemctl enable mongod

systemctl status mongod
```

and after this step the error get occured

[issue on stating mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loZwK.png)

I am trying to install mongodb in my laptop but unable to do it and getting
...............
failed(Result: core-dump).....
................[Active: failed(Result: core-dump)...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oryid.png)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Try to run `mongod --config /etc/mongod`, it should print more errors. Most likely you did not create required directories.

Comment: it's still stick to same error

Comment: I don't think so, have a careful look at the error.